# How to pass a string as an argument to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i need is to be able to pass a string to a javascript function , the function is specified in the onclick event of a div,

```
$("#div").html("<div id='suggestion' onclick='storetag("+response[i]['tagname']+")'><div id='postag' ><center><b>"+response[i]['tag']+"</b></center></div></div>");
```

here i can't pass the response[i]['tagname'] to the storetag() ,since it is a string and requires quetos around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the quotation marks in the strings surrounding the values:

```
$("#div").html("<div id='suggestion' onclick='storetag(\""+response[i]['tagname']+"\")'><div id='postag' ><center><b>"+response[i]['tag']+"</b></center></div></div>");
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Unless you specify what it is that you think is so horrible about the code, I can't even have an opinion about your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline JS where you have to deal with code contained in strings, do this:

```
var div = $('<div id="suggestion"><div id="postag"><center><b></b></center></div></div>');
div.find('b').html(response[i]['tag']).on('click', function() {
    storetag(response[i]['tagname']);
});
$("#div").html(div);
```

That way you create the DOM first and then properly attach an event handler instead of having to put JS code in a string.

In case you run that code in a loop (`i` makes that likely):

- DO NOT use `id="suggestion"`. IDs MUST be unique!
- Use the following JS code so the proper `i` value is used when the handler executes:

  ```
  var div = $('<div id="suggestion"><div id="postag"><center><b></b></center></div></div>');
  div.find('b').html(response[i]['tag']);
  (function(tagname) {
      div.on('click', function() {
          storetag(tagname);
      });
  })(response[i]['tagname']);
  $("#div").html(div);
  ```

Comment: thanx,yes it is being run in a loop
and about id's being unique ,i have specified css rules for the id "suggestion", and i need every div produced by the loop to have the same id,so that i don't have to specify rules for every id the loop produces

Comment: What you are doing is **WRONG**! Use CSS classes instead! You can use them on as many elements as you want.

Comment: hmm,never considered tht ,
thnx again

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#div").html("<div id='suggestion' onclick='storetag(\""+response[i]['tagname']+"\")'><div id='postag' ><center><b>"+response[i]['tag']+"</b></center></div></div>");
```

here i have add \" escape in your code

Comment: This is the correct answer, you're the only person who read the question.

Comment: thanku @web_bod thanks a lot. Appriciated. You can accept this answer also.

Comment: @web_bod: Not the only one... I posted the exact same code a few seconds before Deepad Manwal, but that got downvoted instead of accepted...

Comment: This code makes me want to cry. This is abad solution to the problem that keeps the code unmaintainable and unclear.

Comment: i don't know what you guys are doing things like this. @guffa you are correct and all you also correct. Don't make issue of little things.